# Making 2 lists into one dictionary

Tags: python

is there a way to define a function that takes two lists and makes the elements in the first list the key and the elements in the second list the values of a dictionary?

`names = ['ted','west','tom','jerry','fred']` and another list `ages = [10,23,13,18,12]`
how can i define a function that takes the two lists and returns a dictionary with the names as the key and the scores as the value?

i know that i can turn each list into a dictionary and then append it but I'm not sure how i can place the colons.

Comment: The answer that was marked as duplicate will work for you. But you can also do something like this: `{k:v for k,v in zip(names, ages)}`. This would be how to place those "colons", but you can also call `dict` which works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

[zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) them, followed by a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

```
>>> ages = [10,23,13,18,12]

>>> names = ['ted','west','tom','jerry','fred']

>>> {x[0]:x[1] for x in zip(names, ages)}
{'ted': 10, 'tom': 13, 'fred': 12, 'jerry': 18, 'west': 23}
```

Comment: `dict(zip(names, ages))` works too ... comprehension not needed ...

Comment: @mgilson cool, didn't know dict accepts collection of 2-tuples as args

Comment: how can i store that new dictionary with a variable that i can call?

Comment: like so nameAges = {x[0]:x[1] for x in zip(names, ages)} ?

Comment: @james2121 yes.. also it's a best practise to use variable names like `name_ages` instead of `nameAges` in python